# Firefox extension: Access to main document from sidebar

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm brand new to writing Firefox extensions and I'm trying to create a sidebar which searches for certain elements in the main document and shows info about them in the sidebar. I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) to create the sidebar with no problems.

Problem I'm having now is accessing the main window or document in my sidebar.js file.

The docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#From_a_sidebar) say to use

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                   .rootTreeItem
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
```

But that gives me this error:

> TypeError: window.QueryInterface is not a function

I'm getting the warning:

> The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.

Which makes me think even if the code above worked for me it's not the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages indicate that your code is running in an unprivileged javascript context. `.QueryInterface()` is XPCOM code, i.e. accessing internal browser components which is only available to privileged code.

It is generally not advisable to for "leaf content" (windows/sidebars spawned by addons) to have direct control. Instead your addon main code should coordinate the individual views. Your sidebar should be dumb, just pass messages to addon code and the addon then modifies the content of the tab.

Due [e10s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) various parts of the browser may end up running in separate processes in the future and will not have direct access to each other.

If you're not developing with the [addon-sdk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) - which is designed with message-passing as its primary way of gluing components together - you will have to use the [message manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager) to wire your addon, sidebar and content scripts together.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tabs.create() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create) as in:

```
browser.tabs.create({url:"https://www.google.com"});
```

I also used that documentation and I also got that error. The documentation is too old.

Answer (score 0):

browser.tabs.create({url:"https://www.google.com"})
will work fine